# http2 with self signed invalid certificate

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, http2

HI I tried http2 to use in my application and for that I created self signed certificate which chrome is showing invalid. I just wanted to know if certificates are invalid, can I still use http2 because I am not seeing any improvement after using http2.

My application runs on long running processes which take a lot of time and I thought after using http2 I could gain some improvement,but still after 6 request I have to wait for the tcp to available. I am using nginx.

Comment: Why don't you simply install that self signed certificate in your browser, so that it is accepted as valid?

Comment: I tried the same thing but still I am not able to understand why I have to still wait for the long running request to finish.

Comment: Need far more details. Is HTTP/2 enabled? Add the Protocol field to the Network tab of Developer tools which will answer that definitively. Then add the waterfall diagram of your download to show if you have a networking bottleneck (that HTTP/2 might solve) or just a slow application at server or client side (which it can’t).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HTTP/2 works with self signed certificates:

[image: Picture with h2 and invalid certificate warning]